# Loop through AWS storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have stored pictures on AWS S3 in a bucket and what to retrieve all of the pictures and render them to an EJS template.
I want to store the pictures into an array and then send the array to the EJS template any suggestions?

---

```
app.get("/blogs", function(req, res){

    Blog.find({}, function(err, blogsD){
        if(err){
            console.log("error");
        } else{
          var params = {
              Bucket: "BUCKET NAME", 
              MaxKeys: 2
        };
        var pen = [];
        var pic = s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err){ console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                } else{  
                    for( i = 0; i < data.Contents.length ; i++ ){
                            console.log(data.Contents[i]);
                            pen.push(data.Contents[i].Key);
            }    
          }
        });

       var pac = pic;
            res.render("index", {blogs: blogsD, pac: pac});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Suggestions on what ? It seems you know what needs to be done, want suggestions on scale or design or your code is breaking ?

Comment: when I console log the pen ARRAY its always empty, how do I push the data to the pen ARRAY?

Comment: See what happens if you don't set `MaxKeys: 2`.